# PHP - How to put select from table where query = $query and query2 = $query2

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a table that contains Names, products, and jobs, I want to select from that table  where names = $name and jobs = $job 
How can I do this in PHP 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you got your database connection setup.
You can use this query to select the information:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE names = '". $names ."' AND jobs = '". $job ."' ");
```

Bjorn.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

And just GET the variables like this

```
$names = $_GET['names']

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT names, products, jobs FROM tablename WHERE names=? AND jobs=?")) {

    /* Bind our params */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $names, $jobs);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($names, $products, $jobs);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query(" SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name='{$name}' AND jobs='{$job}'");
```